# SP.Taxonomy get_parent().get_id()

Tags: csom

I have been working with this for awhile. I can get the current items without issue but when i try to get the parent id of an item. Javascript throws an error. I have this sort of working using the Name to get the correct listings. But a Parent GUID would be much better.
here is my code:

```
var termSetName = "Site Navigation";
    var locale = 1033;
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var taxonomySession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(clientContext);
    var termStore = taxonomySession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
    var termSets = termStore.getTermSetsByName(termSetName, locale);
    var termSet = termSets.getByName(termSetName);
    var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();
    clientContext.load(taxonomySession);
    clientContext.load(termStore);
    clientContext.load(termSet);
    //clientContext.load(terms, 'Include(IsRoot, Labels, TermsCount, CustomSortOrder, Id, IsAvailableForTagging, Name, PathOfTerm, Parent, TermSet.Name)');
    clientContext.load(terms);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function onSuccess() {
        var enumerator = terms.getEnumerator();
        var s = '';
        var j = new Array();
        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var spTerm = enumerator.get_current();
            var name = spTerm.get_name();
            var isRoot = (spTerm.get_isRoot().toString() == 'true');
            var termPath = spTerm.get_pathOfTerm();
            var termParent = spTerm.get_parent();
            var custProps = spTerm.get_localCustomProperties();
            var id = spTerm.get_id().toString();
            var parId = termParent.get_id(); //Error is here
            var pth = custProps['_Sys_Nav_TargetUrl'];
            if (!pth) {
                pth = custProps['_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl'];
            }
            j.push({ Name: name, Id: id, IsRoot: isRoot, Path: pth, TermPath: termPath, SubItems: new Array() });
        }
        CallBack(j);
    }, function onFailure(args) {
        CallBack(null);
    });
```

Comment: I would check few things like are you using reusable terms it could be issue.and also you should explicitly load the parent term before accessing the function.check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136168/get-parent-term-set-id-using-jsom

Answer (score 1):

You will need an async execute and loading before querying parent.

```
    context.load(termParent);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
      function onSuccess() {
         var parId = termParent.get_id(); //Congrats you found your parent
      }, function onFailure(args) {
        //you failed 
      }
   );
```